# 'init_s1_value' not declared in scope

Tags: c++, arduino

```
const int init_s1_value=analogRead(sensor1);

void setup(){
    init(loc_1,init_s1_value); // this line works fine
}

    void loop(){
        int s1_value = analogRead(sensor1); 
        digitalWrite(L1,HIGH); 
        if (s1_value != init_sl_value){ //this line is highlighted!
        ......
    }
```

Hi, I'm new here and am encountering a problem where 'init_s1_value' not declared in scope, even though i declared it globally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

```
init_sl_value
```

is not the same as

```
init_s1_value
```